# pass an object into a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication, uicollectionviewcell

I am having an issue using the FBSDK inside a UICollectionViewCell. I am getting the warning that the code will not execute after a return statement. I have successfully implemented the Facebook login in a UIViewController but am getting errors when trying to do it inside a CollectionViewCell class. Thanks for any and all help!

```
class LoginCell: UICollectionViewCell, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    lazy var FBloginButton: UIButton = {
        let customButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        customButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        customButton.setTitle("Login With Facebook", for: .normal)
        customButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        customButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        return customButton

        customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomFBButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    }()


    // am I passing an objective from: correctly below...????
    func handleCustomFBButton() {
        FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self.delegate as! UIViewController!) { (result, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Custom FB Login Button Failed")
                return
            }
            self.showEmailAddress()
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("did log out of facebook...")
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        showEmailAddress()
    }


    func showEmailAddress() {
        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
        guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else { return }

        let credentials = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Something went wrong with our FB user: ", error ?? "")
                return
            }
            print("Successfully logged in with our user: ", user ?? "")
        })

        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start { (connection, result, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Failed to start graph request:", err ?? "")
                return
            }
            print(result ?? "")
        }
    }


    weak var delegate: LoginControllerDelegate?

    func handleLogin() {
        delegate?.finishLoggingIn()
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(logoImageView)
        addSubview(emailTextField)
        addSubview(passwordTextField)
        addSubview(loginButton)
        addSubview(FBloginButton)

        _ = logoImageView.anchor(centerYAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: -230, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 160, heightConstant: 160)
        logoImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        _ = FBloginButton.anchor(loginButton.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 32, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 32, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 50)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Whenever `return` is invoked inside any function that implies the end
  of that function implementation.
- Any *code* written *post* a `return` statement will not be **executed**.
- The problem in given implementation lies in `lazy var FBloginButton: UIButton`, post a `return` statement button-target is being set-up.

Appropriate implementation to fix the issue would be like:

```
lazy var FBloginButton: UIButton = {
        let customButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        customButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        customButton.setTitle("Login With Facebook", for: .normal)
        customButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        customButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomFBButton), for: .touchUpInside)

        return customButton
    }()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning before setting the target.

Try placing the `customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomFBButton), for: .touchUpInside)` statement before the `return customButton` statement.